# update last 8 characters in a column in SSRS 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i got one requirement like , in a column i have 1500 records , now i need to update only date value in that column

my input is

Test

synmrwek_name_09082013
synmrtyuio_name-09082013
ertwer_name_09072013

now in the above test column i have to update only date as current date or any other unique date. if it is possible to get today date dynamically it is good or else we can pass manual date.

Expected OutPut is

synmrwek_name_05012013 
synmrtyuio_name-05012013
ertwer_name_05012013

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have 1500 records in a column, the first thing you have to do is normalize that data into a real table. Then, updating the date would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

When your db contain such type of data in which a single column in a record consists of multiple information, then it is more advisable to use any client side technology like C# for manipulation such data. T-Sql is an excellent for Db side business logic, but it have its own limitations.

For example in T-Sql, we don't have any string function like "LastIndexOf()" like we have in .Net Languages.

So for your problem, it is recommended to use a client-side technology as the persormance will hardly make any difference for just 1500 tuples.

Comment: Amit thank you for your reply , but i have to full fill it with help of sql query only.i did upto some level i.e i can able to get only date part but i am not able to update it.                        select SUBSTRING(test,1,right(test,8)-8) from test

Comment: Hi , i got my required result with the below query                                        update TEST
set TEST=REPLACE(TEST ,'04112013','8112013')